# Get server Port in web application at server start

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I need to retrieve server information like Server IP and Port at server startup. 
I am using Spring and hibernet in my project and Glassfish (and tomcat) is the application server.

I know that I can get the IP and Port information from request, but there is no request at server startup.

I found on net after some search that IP address can be retrieved as follows:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

but I did not find any method to retrive the current Port of the server. I am hoping to find API from app server which will provide this information. I am using Spring in my application and thus any indications from Spring API will also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Well you should configure port in your web.xml as param and read it out in your code using `ServletContext` or you can use [this poor hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080357/java-ee-getting-servlet-container-port)

Answer (score 0):

A server may be listening to multiple ports on multiple names, so you cannot be certain that the one chosen automatically is the one you really want.

Question is what you need it for.

- If it is for giving URL backs in requests then use the information in requests.
- If it is for logging or announcement with ZeroConf, then consider writing application server specific code asking it about its configuration.
- If all else fails, explicitly pass in the information through e.g. system properties or JNDI.